# Java: Utility function to create a new sorted list

Tags: java, collections

I find myself sometimes doing this:

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(vii.slots.keySet());
Collections.sort(keys);
for(String index : keys) {
    ...
```

Is there a utlity method (in commons, Guava, wherever) that does this in one line, like:

```
for(String index : sorted(vii.slots.keySet())) {
    ...
```

Sorry if this is a FAQ but I failed to find this after a bit of web searching and I'm sure a Java guru will answer this in five seconds flat.

Thanks

Comment: What type is `slots`?

Comment: @Reimeus Map<String,VarInfo> - VarInfo is a class within my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guava's [ordering](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) might be what you're looking for:

For your usage:

```
for (String index : Ordering.<String>natural().sortedCopy(vii.slots.keySet())) {
      System.out.println(index);
}
```

A simplistic sorting with a natural order would look something like:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("pops");
    list.add("chops");
    list.add("zebra");
    list.add("xam");

    for (String str : Ordering.<String>natural().sortedCopy(list)) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Gives:

```
chops
pops
xam
zebra
```

`Ordering` can also work with custom `Comparator` instances to sort in the desired sequence.

Comment: I don't see a need for guava since TreeMap or TreeSet maintain ordered collections and can be constructed in a single line without needing an extra dependency.

Comment: @LanceJava And I don't contest that, there are different ways to fulfill a requirement and moreover OP has explicitly mentioned 'utility' and 'Guava' in his post without any constraints of external dependancy.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String,VarInfo> sorted = new TreeMap<String,VarInfo>(vii.slots);
for (Map.Entry<String,VarInfo> entry : sorted) {
   doStuff(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: A classical illustration of my pet peeve: Using the right collection for the job!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you need some kind of `SortedSet` instead of `List`. If you need to maintain a number of occurences of each element - try using a Guava's [TreeMultiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html)

An example:

```
Multiset<Integer> multiSet = TreeMultiset.create();
multiSet.add(2);
multiSet.add(2);
multiSet.add(1);
multiSet.add(5);
multiSet.add(6);
multiSet.add(6);
multiSet.add(3);
for (Integer i : multiSet) {
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

the output will be:

```
1223566
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to write an Iterable class that will take your map and itereate over the keys; then you get your one-line invocation and don't need anothe rlibrary to depend on.